# How to SELECT from multiple ranges of time

Tags: sql-server

Lets say I have a table in SQLServer named Events. It contains some events with time stamp.

```
ID  TimeStamp             EventDescription
1   '2019-04-04 08:20'    Machine Error 1
2   '2019-04-04 09:01'    Machine Error 2
3   '2019-04-05 09:23'    Machine Error 3
4   '2019-04-05 12:23'    Machine Error 4
5   '2019-04-06 11:33'    Machine Error 5
6   '2019-04-06 18:07'    Machine Error 6
7   '2019-04-07 12:23'    Machine Error 7
```

In addition I have second table named Ranges. It contains ranges of time.

```
ID  From                  To
1   '2019-04-04 08:00'    '2019-04-04 09:00'
2   '2019-04-05 10:30'    '2019-04-05 16:00' 
3   '2019-04-06 10:00'    '2019-04-06 12:00'
```

I need to SELECT events from table Events where TimeStamp IS between ranges of time in table Ranges.

The result:

```
ID  TimeStamp             EventDescription
1   '2019-04-04 08:20'    Machine Error 1
4   '2019-04-05 12:23'    Machine Error 4
5   '2019-04-06 11:33'    Machine Error 5
```

I have no idea what to do.
Do I have to use dynamic SQL to build this query?

Answer (score 3):

Correlated subquery can be used here.

```
Select * from Events E
where exists (select 1 from Ranges where e.TimeStamp between [From] and [To])
```

Answer (score 2):

I created your data as temp tables:

```
SELECT 1 ID,  CAST('2019-04-04 08:20' AS DATETIME) TimeStamp, 'Machine Error 1' EventDescription
INTO #Events
UNION
SELECT 2 ID,  CAST('2019-04-04 09:01' AS DATETIME) TimeStamp, 'Machine Error 2' EventDescription
UNION
SELECT 3 ID,  CAST('2019-04-05 09:23' AS DATETIME) TimeStamp, 'Machine Error 2' EventDescription
UNION
SELECT 4 ID,  CAST('2019-04-05 12:23' AS DATETIME) TimeStamp, 'Machine Error 2' EventDescription
UNION
SELECT 5 ID,  CAST('2019-04-06 11:33' AS DATETIME) TimeStamp, 'Machine Error 2' EventDescription
UNION
SELECT 6 ID,  CAST('2019-04-06 18:07' AS DATETIME) TimeStamp, 'Machine Error 2' EventDescription
UNION
SELECT 7 ID,  CAST('2019-04-07 12:34' AS DATETIME) TimeStamp, 'Machine Error 2' EventDescription


SELECT 1 ID, CAST('2019-04-04 08:00' AS DATETIME) [From], CAST('2019-04-04 09:00' AS DATETIME) [To]
INTO #Ranges
UNION
SELECT 2 ID, CAST('2019-04-05 10:30' AS DATETIME) [From], CAST('2019-04-05 16:00'  AS DATETIME) [To]
UNION
SELECT 3 ID, CAST('2019-04-06 10:00' AS DATETIME) [From], CAST('2019-04-06 12:00' AS DATETIME) [To]
```

And then it's as simple as joining them together:

```
SELECT E.*
FROM #Ranges R
JOIN #Events E ON E.TimeStamp BETWEEN R.[From] AND R.[To]
```